# MathJax is breaking in short expressions frequently today.

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, comment

Formerly MathJax in comments broke if you had too many consecutive non-blank spaces, and too many was a moderately large number.  When it breaks, you see MathJax code in red letters rather than the intended rendered notation.

But today it's been breaking in that way very frequently in short expressions.  Can that get fixed?

Comment: E.g., I just suffered from this with $|f(x)-f(a)|=0<\epsilon$ in a comment (and I see it happens here again: Seem a space is introduced in the middle of `epsilon`

Comment: Testing $|f(x)-f(a)|=0<\upsilon$. And also Testing $|f(x)-f(a)|=0<\delta$

Comment: @mixedmath Are you experimenting with redundant white space?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was. I'm not quite sure what's up. But that it want to add a space exactly 4 characters into epsilon or upsilon and whatnot is a bit odd.

Comment: @mixedmath That's twenty characters without space (including the opening `$`). Used to be eighty.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a bit surprised that $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda$ renders fine. Oh! It doesn't! (I lied --- I thought I'd just tested that) Indeed, 20 characters seems to be a new thing.

Comment: If I guessed right and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332569/urls-in-comments-not-being-parsed-correctly) has the same cause, things should be fixed (in code, not sure when the next build is rolled out, may take a bit).

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to be just the break of commands, but fractions also don't center properly. More details here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24839/mathjax-doesnt-work-properly-in-comment (10k only, I deleted it when I realized ~3 minutes after posting that it was a dupe (oops...))

Comment: Test: \frac{\partial}{\partial x}: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.  \frac{\partial}{\par‌​tial\theta}: $\frac{\partial}{\par‌​tial\theta}$.

Comment: When I wrote \frac{\partial}{\par‌​tial\theta} once today, the denominator looked fine but the numerator had $\text{“} {\partial} \text{''}$ off to the extreme left (but still above the horizontal bar). $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I had it the other way around here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894301/a-simple-integral-int-25-frac-gamma-x-log-left-fracx21x2-1-ri, where the numerator was fine but the denominator is off to the left, but still below the horizontal bar.

Comment: @MichaelHardy $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ vs. $\frac∂{∂\theta}$ (\frac∂{∂\theta})

Answer (score 14):

A quick note. We know what's going on, it's a change which had some side effects. I'll take a stab very soon.

---

Update: It looks better now, as you need 60 consecutive unbroken characters to replicate instead of 20. However, it's not finished. Tomorrow I'll simply disable the line breaking shenanigans for comments that have MathJax in them.

---

Update: this is now fixed. Comments which contain mathjax do not receive separators.

Comment: So you wrote this stub about the stab. Nice. :P

Comment: In case it might be relevant, today I had a comment in which a whitespace mysteriously appeared in the middle of a \equiv. (i.e. it split the word). The problem disappeared after an edit. Very strange.

Comment: [@MichaelHardy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/mathjax-is-breaking-in-short-expressions-frequently-today#comment97130_24836)'s comment with a `\partial` in a fraction still seems to have an issue.

Comment: @LSpice this just [came up in chat too](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31769192#31769192)  A possible explanation is that in that comment the (non-visible) separator was included explicitly in the actual source of the comment (likely inadvertently via a copy paste) as opposed to being automatically inserted on rendering (which is now prevented).

Comment: @LSpice sorry for yet another comment but it just occurred to me how to test it. *Copy* the uncompiled \par‌​tial from that comment that does not render well (that is the last one) and use it by pasting it. This one will always break. But typing it out there will be no problem.  `$\par‌​tial$ $\par‌​tial$ $\par‌​tial$ $\partial$` $\par‌​tial$ $\par‌​tial$ $\par‌​tial$ $\partial$ (First three break.) Likely some editors could also show the character, but I don't have one handy (and/or do not know how to do it).

Comment: @quid, I can't figure out how to make Firefox display them, but pasting into `vim` with `:set list` indeed shows `$\par<200c><200b>tial$` for the first 3 and plain ol' `$\partial` for the last.  Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice. MichaelHardy's comment has some invisible characters embedded *in the source*. The rendering is perfect.

Comment: Indeed, @quid pointed that out [above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/mathjax-is-breaking-in-short-expressions-frequently-today/24838#comment97181_24838).  Thanks!